# Azure SQL Database Creation Issue

Tags: sql-server, azure

About 11 hours ago I've started a SQL database creation operation on Azure and it is still being processed. Since my other databases almost took seconds to be installed, it is obvious that there is a technical problem with this one.

AFAIK there is no option for a user to cancel the current process and start a new one. I have also tried to create another but the system throws the following error:

> Unable to edit or replace deployment 'Microsoft.SQL.NewDatabase':
>   previous deployment from '11/24/2015 9:01:59 PM' is still active
>   (expiration time is '12/1/2015 9:01:59 PM').

Since I haven't purchased any support package I also cannot request it from the Azure team.

Comment: Isn't it a must to assign the SQL DB to a resource group whenever you're creating a new one? If you are asking whether I'm trying to deploy it in a new server or an existing one, I have tried both of them but the result did not change.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've got a similar issue in that I've deleted a database instance and then attempted to recreate it. I'm now prevented from creating any new database on my account until the expiry time (which is ludicrously in 7 days time).

Comment: Unfortunately I have not been able to solve it. The thing I have performed was creating a new db on an existing server and use it. (Since I also do not have an existing paid support, I could not create a support ticket and get a proper solution for it either) I am planning to move my db to a new instance whenever I'm done with my required ops.

Comment: I came back after the weekend and found that the 'pending task' ending up completing (successfully) however on when I tried to deploy to the database I ended up with a complaint that a file already exists. I could subsequently delete the db and recreate it this time with no issues. Not an answer unfortunately, just had to wait a weekend for it to work again!

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to do it at the end. Wish that Azure team, at least provide support for issues that has nothing to do with the user but the system without expecting a paid support.